# How Can I get value from progressbar JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, user-interface, progress-bar

How can I get value from progressbar jquery ui?
I try to get value: 40, 70 and 90
For Example
code:

```
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/96dLntah/1/
```

Comment: i don't get the statement ** I try to get the value: 40, 70 and 90**  because you are animating the progress bar manually using `setInterrval` then what is the point of getting the value when you are setting it yourself?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn’t this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)